# Failed to register a ServiceWorker

Tags: javascript, service-worker

everyone! I have an issue with ServiceWorker. I receive a message about error:

'TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.'

I know sure as hell that this code works.

This link is for registration SW: https://github.com/Paveldub/simple-sw/blob/master/js/main.js

There're two types of examples:

1) https://github.com/Paveldub/simple-sw/blob/master/sw_cached_pages.js

2) https://github.com/Paveldub/simple-sw/blob/master/sw_cached_site.js

Can anyone help me. Thank you =)

Comment: Judging from the path, looks like you need `.register('../../sw_cached_pages.js')`

Comment: no, I don't think so. ((

Comment: Right, it should actually be `.register('sw_cached_pages.js')` since the file is here: `https://paveldub.github.io/simple-sw/sw_cached_pages.js` but the browser is looking for `https://paveldub.github.io/sw_cached_pages.js`

Comment: hmmmm... nothing..

Comment: Works fine for me.